# Kiosk Mode not available in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, kiosk

It seems that I cannot `Get started` to set up a Kiosk account in Windows 11.

Why do I not see the option to set it up?

[image]

Comment: Are you on Windows 11 Home?

Comment: @harrymc Yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kiosk feature is not supported in the Windows 10/11 Home editions.

Sorry for the negative answer, but you will need to upgrade your version
of Windows 11 in order to have this mode.

Reference :
[Configure kiosks and digital signs on Windows desktop editions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-methods)

> **Which edition of Windows client will the kiosk run?**
>
> All of the configuration methods work for Windows client Enterprise
> and Education; some of the methods work for Windows Pro. Kiosk mode
> isn't available on Windows Home.

Comment: Thank you! I was reading on the Microsoft Kiosk page that it was available for Windows 10 Pro / Enterprise and Windows 11. So I assumed that all versions of Windows 11 were included, but I guess the same applies to Windows 11